# ActiveRecord find associated records of associated records in one query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm trying to find an ActiveRecord and/or SQL way to only use 1 query for the following

**Get all chapters written by an author given that an author has_many books and a book has_many chapters**

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :chapters
end

class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
end
```

This works but it uses two queries

```
Chapter.where(book_id: author.books.map(&:id))

Book Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `books`.* FROM `books`  WHERE `books`.`author_id` = 1
Chapter Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `chapters`.* FROM `chapters`  WHERE `chapters`.`book_id` IN (1, 2, 3)
```

This works but it returns an array object not an ActiveRecord relation object

```
author.books.map(&:chapters)
```

Comment: Why does it uses two queries? Can you add the two queries in your question? I test a similar scenario in one of my projects and it only uses one query... (I'm using RoR 3.2)

Comment: It used two queries because ```author.books.map(&:id)``` is the first query. I've included the queries in the question for you

Comment: Yep... I checked it out after comment this, and I realize that the first time you search that, it will be use two queries, but after that it will use only one! (assuming that you instantiate `author` in another variable)... It's good to know this behavior to, despite it's not the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a has_many through association:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  has_many :chapters, through: :books
end
```

And then use it like:

```
author = Author.find(...)
author.chapters
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd seen the use of ```through: :books``` several times before but never stopped to understand it or when to use it. Now i know :)